# Move Object On a Curved Path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script that I am using to move an object in an Arch, but the issue that I am having is that if one of the Y values is negative for (Start and/or End), the object curves down and around. What I would like is for it to always curve up and around no matter what the Y value is. How can I acheive this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveArch : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 startPosition;
    public Vector3 endPosition;
    public float resetTime = 1f;
    public float journeyTime = 1f;
    public ArchDirection archDirection;

    public enum ArchDirection {
        Positive,
        Negative
    }

    private float startTime;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 center = (startPosition + endPosition) * 0.1F;
        center -= new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        Vector3 riseRelCenter = startPosition - center;
        Vector3 setRelCenter = endPosition - center;

        float fracComplete = (Time.time - startTime) / journeyTime;

        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Slerp(riseRelCenter, setRelCenter, fracComplete);
        transform.localPosition += center;

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.localPosition, endPosition) <= 0.1f) {
            Invoke("resetMoon", resetTime);
        }
    }

    void resetMoon(){
        startTime = Time.time;
        transform.localPosition = startPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `Math.Abs`?

Comment: Yes, it's absolute value, pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.